# select all first records

Tags: sql, select

I need select only the first record for each person.

If `Status=1` is active record else is historic record

```
app       NoPerson   Status      Name     CreationDateTime
========  ========  ========   ========   ================
1         1         0           Ali       2022-08-30 11:31:53.117
1         1         1           Alison    2022-09-30 17:14:08.027
1         2         1           Charly    2022-09-30 17:18:22.147
2         1         1           Andy      2022-11-20 19:19:13.353
2         2         0           Alann     2022-10-13 10:28:23.910
2         2         0           Alannn    2022-10-13 11:35:23.910
2         2         1           Alan      2022-10-14 10:28:23.910
2         3         1           Marc      2022-10-14 11:35:23.910
```

Well I need to show only the first records that have been made. Like this:

```
app       NoPerson   Status      Name     CreationDateTime
========  ========  ========   ========   ================
1         1         0           Ali       2022-08-30 11:31:53.117
1         2         1           Charly    2022-09-30 17:18:22.147
2         1         1           Andy      2022-11-20 19:19:13.353
2         2         0           Alann     2022-10-13 10:28:23.910
2         3         1           Marc      2022-10-14 11:35:23.910
```

The only way to know that it is the first record is by the creation date being the smallest

Comment: One option: `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( <a row for the same person with an older date> )`.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using, so as to only get answers that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for most of DBMS, mysql/mariadb, postgresql...

Using `row_number()` to order rows grouped by **app** and **NoPerson**, then we get first row from each partition :

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by app,NoPerson order by CreationDateTime) as row_id
  from mytable
)
select app, NoPerson, Status, Name, CreationDateTime
from cte
where row_id = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ESI1HVeA)